# Jerk in UI with notification bar

Tags: android

In my application I have two `Activities` `A` and `B`. In `Activity` `A`, i disable the `notification bar`  in manifest but in `Activity` B `notification` bar is enabled. While navigating from `Activity` A to `Activity` B there is some jerk in User Interface. Can any body help me in this.

Comment: define "jerk" and we might be able to help you...

Answer (score 0):

I think jerk is happening because the phone/tablet on which you are testing either:

- has a weak GPU and thus cannot render the transition fluidly, or
- the version of Android does not support it.

This is *not* a problem with your app. Ideally there should be a smooth slide-in, like on my Nexus 7.

A nice way to solve it is by either having the notification-bar on in both `Activities` or off in both. No jerk :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried performance testing your app?  Your UI could be causing the problem.  Do you see the same Jerk if you temporarily disable the notification bar?  Have you tried using the [Hierarchy Viewer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAgE7saQUUY) on Activity B?